# Integrate Keycloak with Camunda - custom permissions

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, camunda

I manage to integrate Keycloak with Camunda to have admin group and I am able to login. Next what I am trying to do is to have second group tasklist-group which will have access only to tasklist. I created tasklist-group on keycloak and I see it’s synced in ACT_ID_GROUP table in DB, but how could I add permissions to that group to see Tasklist through keycloak and that to be reflected to Camunda ?
I am using Camunda 7 - 7.17 and Spring boot 2.6.6
and plugin camunda-platform-7-keycloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered on Forum Camunda:

> adding permissions through the identity provider is not supported by Camunda Platform 7. You will have to use the Authorization panel in the Admin area of the Camunda webapp.

> If you require the authorization management, you will have to create a custom solution.

https://forum.camunda.io/t/integrate-keycloak-with-camunda-custom-permissions/45985